# Setting different spaces for tab for Java and Scala in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, scala

In Java, the usual convention is to have tab size 4. In Scala it's 2.
In a Scala + Java project, is it possible to set these different tab sizes, depending on the language file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Windows > Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations

Find *.scala in the list and ensure Scala editor is selected as the first option.
if it is, then we just need to change the preferences for the scala editor.

Then:

> project > properties > Scala formatter

The either select project specific settings or workspace specific settings, there should be an option where for how many spaces you want.

Comment: And make sure you uncheck "Indent using tabs"!

Comment: I've got "Indent using tabs" turned off, all these steps are OK.. but it still uses a default indent & tab of 4 in my Scala files. Exceptionally inconvenient :(